# Disabling HTML Filtering When Importing Into WordPress Multisite

Tags: import

A number of the sites I'm migrating to a WordPress Multisite instance have embedded videos and iframes within posts. Rather than convert each post to the kosher way of doing video embeds, I'd rather disable the WordPress functionality which strips out the embeds on import. Disabling the stripping when editing a post was [as simple as disabling the kses filter](http://github.com/danielbachhuber/Unfiltered-HTML).

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what I need to disable for importing posts. At the moment I suspect the wp_insert_post() method but haven't narrowed down the filter. Any ideas?

**Update:** This is specific to WordPress Multisite. Importing into a single WordPress site works just fine.

Comment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14818

Answer (score 3):

Hook int `force_filtered_html_on_import` and return `FALSE`. See [ticket #14818](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14818).

```
add_filter( 'force_filtered_html_on_import' , '__return_false' );
```

By default this is set to `TRUE` in `wp-includes/ms-default-filters.php`.