# When migrating all backslashes were stripped and special signs are converted in html entities

Tags: import

I'm migrating my wordpress-blog and so imported my complete content with WordPress Importer 0.6.1. (which is the latest today (July, 2th 2015). My mySQL-server version is 5.1.56-community.

Unfortunatley two problems appear on my new blog after import:
1.) all my backslashes are gone, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files -> C:Program Files
```

2.) some signs inside code-areas (formatted with the "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved" plugin) are encrypted with HTML entities, e.g.

```
 <  ->  &lt;   
 >  ->  &gt;    
 "  ->  &quot;    
 (...)
```

3.) Links inside code-area (formatted with the "SyntaxHighlighter Evolved" plugin) are replaced, e.g.

```
http://www.google.com  ->  <a class="linkification-ext" href="http://www.google.com" title="Linkification: http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>
```

First I looked at the backup.xml (which was created by the export tool of wordpress.com) and all backslashes are shown correct there.
Second I looked in the database and really all backslashes are missing.

Creating a plugin before export (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50560/75467) isn't a solution for me, because the hoster (wordpress.com) doesn't let me that deep in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably remove HTML entity filtering on import, using:

```
add_filter( 'force_filtered_html_on_import' , '__return_false' );
```

as answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139414/41259).

Comment: thx, I tried, but it doesn't help

Comment: Okay! I wonder then if it would be a database collation conflict. Or an issue with the encoding of the XML file.

Comment: Thx again - honestly I don't know. Anyhow, I've found a workaround for question 1 & 2. Only question 3 is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (in respect to a good Q&A policy) all problems unvealed to be independent from each other. The only common base is, that they all happen directly after the migration of my blog from wordpress.de to my self-hosted blog.

### Missing backslashes

Probably that problem is caused by WordPress Importer.
Maybe the root cause of this problem is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12770704/1777526

#### Solution

1. I replaced in a texteditor the backslashes with two backslashes in the backup.xml
2. I downloaded "Bulk delete" plugin
3. I deleted all posts and pages permanently(!)
4. I imported the changed backup.xml again and all the backslashes are correct now.

### Escaping of special characters to HTML entities

Probably that problem is caused by the export tool of wordpress.com (don't know which plugin they use).
Every text that is enclosed by "SyntaxHighlighter Exolved" markup, e.g.

```
[sourcecode language="text"]
bla bla 
[sourcecode]
```

… is literally displayed. So `&lt;` is displayed as `&lt;` and not as `<`.

#### Solution

I don't know if it can break something or matches all special characters, but for me the following SQL clean-up script seems to work properly:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&amp;', '&');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&gt;', '>');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&lt;', '<');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '&quot;', '"');
```

### Converting all my URLs in my codeareas

I found out, that it happens only in my Firefox, and e.g. not on Chrome. Responsible for that problem (that the most readers of my blog probably never mentioned) was the Firefox add-on called Linkification (in version 1.3.8.).

#### Solution

After disabling Linkification add-on in Firefox, my problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to disable all plugins before importing and the problem was solved. I believe the issue is with SEO plugins usually.